# Integrate Facebook login on my website

Tags: facebook

I've tried to integrate fb login on my website and can't get it to work. I referred to other posts and tutorials but I'm still not able to get it work.

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Login Page2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({appId: '317329008329948', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                login();
            });m
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
                logout();
            });

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.session) {
                    greet();
                }
            });
        };
        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
                '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());

        function login(){
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                alert('You have successfully logged in, '+response.name+"!");
            });
        }
        function logout(){
            alert('You have successfully logged out!');
        }
        function greet(){
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                alert('Welcome, '+response.name+"!");
            });
        }


    </script>
<fb:login-button autologoutlink='true' perms='email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream'></fb:login-button>

</body>
 </html>
```

I keep getting this error: "An error occurred please try again later"

Comment: an error in your application settings on facebook probably

Comment: after  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                login();
            });

You have a stray 'm' . Is that a typo or are you getting a js error because of that?

Comment: @tommy- ya that was a typo but still m getting the same error.

Comment: @bool.dev- i'll look into them again but they seem to be quite right.

Answer (score 3):

Please don't blindly use the callback as Facebook shows in their examples and ignore the response value. Facebook will call the events even though that action really wasn't performed. That's why they give you the "response" variable.

You should look at the value of the properties of the response variable before deciding what to do.

I gave the same advice to markzzz and it worked for him

[Why auth.logout is called after auth.login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785737/why-auth-logout-is-called-after-auth-login/9794068#9794068)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience,
I get this error when I put my fb code on a site other than specified in app settings.

So, I suggest you to run in code on the same url which you have specified in `Site URL` in app settings.